# C++ Visual Studio 2015 CLR Windows Form Namespace error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hi I'am trying to create a function that want to take in the class for the Form thats created with the Windows Form Wizard. The Visual Studio is using the project name as a namespace to the Form class 'NewCustomerForm' but whene I try to create a function with the class as an argument it says whene I compile the code I get this error message:

```
Error   C2871   'Project1': a namespace with this name does not exist
```

This is the file it complain on `NewCustomerTab.h`:

```
#ifndef __NewCustomerTab_H__
#define __NewCustomerTab_H__

#include "NewCustomerForm.h"

using namespace Project1;

ref class CNewCustomerTab :
    public System::Windows::Forms::TabPage{
public:
    CNewCustomerTab(NewCustomerForm^);
private:
    System::Windows::Forms::Form^ form1;
};
```

And this is the Form class `NewCustomerForm.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "NewCustomerTab.h"

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for NewCustomerForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class NewCustomerForm : public Form
    {
    public:
        NewCustomerForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~NewCustomerForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    public: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^  panel1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->panel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Panel());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->panel1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->panel1->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
            this->panel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->panel1->Name = L"panel1";
            this->panel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(842, 563);
            this->panel1->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 24, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(251, 31);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(229, 37);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"New Customer";
            // 
            // NewCustomerForm
            // 
            //this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            //this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(842, 563);
            this->Controls->Add(this->panel1);
            this->Name = L"NewCustomerForm";
            this->Text = L"NewCustomerForm";
            this->panel1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->panel1->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}
```

What do I do wrong I include the Form class file and there it says that `Project1` is a namespace.

Comment: Your NewCustomerForm.h has an #include *before* it declares the namespace.  Note the circular dependencies you have, NewCustomerForm.h requires NewCustomerTab.h to be included and NewCustomerTab.h requires NewCustomerForm.h to be included.  That cannot work.  You have to do the C++ dance with incomplete type declarations and moving code into a .cpp file that #includes both .h files.  Or write better code, ideally the CNewCustomerTab class should not need to know that it is being used by the NewCustomerForm class.  Using the C# language to do this is recommended.

Comment: Thanks Hans it was the Include that made the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must compile with the Common Language Runtime Support (/clr).
Rigth click on your solution, in configuration properties, select general, and select clr for Common Language Runtime Support.

Comment: Just as a remark; this is a Project setting, not a Solution settings.